# simultaneous confidence bands for derivative of density

Tags: r, confidence-interval, derivative, density-estimation

There is lots of attention on confidence bands for regression functions, but I
see not many for densities and even less for *derivative* of density. In particular, I would like to know some theory and
hopefully R code or at least start for an algorithm.

For example, consider the following simulated "data":

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
```

I would like uniform confidence bands regarding density of x, e.g. at 95% level. It would show something like a positive and increasing derivative up to -1
(that is where the inflection point is), and positive but decreasing derivative
from -1 to 0. Then negative and decreasing from 0 to 1 (second inflection
point), then negative but increasing.

By the way, when I say "increasing" I'm talking about the derivative increasing
(i.e. positive second derivative).

I did literature search and all I found was this:
http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~nickl/Site/__files/AOS738.pdf

It is (very much) too technical for my abilities however, and not a chance I can figure out the R code for it.

I wonder if I can use function `kdde` from the `ks` library. Can I bootstrap from original data and apply `kdde` to bootstraps? Is there a paper containing a theorem telling me this is valid approach?

Can you please provide both theory justification and R code showing why proposed method works?

Comment: The flavor of your final remarks is nonparametric.  However, it's not possible to develop a useful fully non-parametric theory of confidence bands for the derivative of a density, simply because the derivative can be made arbitrarily large or small at any location whatsoever without changing the likelihood of the data.  Concentrate, then, on identifying assumptions you can make about the density to eliminate such possibilities.  This would likely lead you towards developing a parametric model.

Comment: @whuber thank you for interesting comment. I had never thought about such. Do you have reference for this discussion? Why is the problem different from identification of regression function itself? in-between points cant we do whatever we want without changing likelihood? But that is why we penalize rough smooths (e.g. penalized spline). Doesn't same concept work for derivatives?

Comment: You seem to confound the ideas of a density and a regression function--these are different concepts altogether.  Estimating a density is not a regression problem in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @whuber Yes I am indeed confused and trying to improve. Thank you for helping. To make sure I understand your final point: are you suggesting it is impossible to get a consistent (i.e. asymptotic) 95% confidence interval for the derivative of a density, without making some assumptions? If such is true, then it would be nice to know the minimal assumptions to achieve consistency.

Comment: I'm not sure there are *minimal* assumptions *per se*.  There are various kinds of assumptions that could be made.  Surely the problem you are dealing with will suggest some appropriate ones.

Comment: @whuber could you possibly give a density such that bootstrapped CI will not be valid for derivative? i.e. I still don't understand why only assuming density exists is not strong enough asymptotic assumption. If I see density and I see how bootstrap fails, I will be able to have more practical understanding. Thank you for all of the helping!

Comment: The derivative is not the kind of functional for which the Bootstrap will work.  If you try it, you will be making deductions about your method of estimating densities from data--but they won't tell you anything at all about the derivatives of the true underlying density.  One has to wonder why you are focused on this: just what information would the derivative of the density hold that is of interest?

Comment: in my honors thesis, I am exploring evolution. There is theory that for a certain trait in animals, (for example length of tongue) that nature will find the optimal length. There's possible to have more than one equilibria (such as bimodal). By looking at derivative, I can study where in the density spectrum a certain subspecies (e.g. known to have a certain value of tongue length) locates. If derivative is 0, then it might be at mode (or might be in tail or saddle, but mode is possible). So I want to test if deriv is 0. I don't know well stats theory. But thanks to you I am learning a lot!

Comment: That's a narrower question than estimating the derivative or finding confidence bands for it.  Thus, you are more likely to get useful answers if you edit your post to reflect what you're actually trying to do!

Comment: @whuber I see. Thank you. My purpose was also to learn a general concept so further my intuition of statistics. And even though no answer to general question, I already learned much thank you to your comments. Thank you!